# Security Attack on data url in html

Tags: javascript, html, security

```html
<a href="#recommend_tab" id="vendors_reco" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-url="/my/plan/getvendors/{{id}}/" aria-expanded="true">
```

I am using the above code in html and it is a legacy code, How can I prevent security attack here as the attacker can substitute values in id = let's say 1647353 and get the results for another query.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is named "insecure direct object references". This is a nice piece of info I mostly agree with: https://blog.detectify.com/2016/05/25/owasp-top-10-insecure-direct-object-reference-4/

What I don't agree with is that there is only one solution to the problem. There are two:

1. You either make the references secure by performing authentication and authorization
2. You make the references indirect and hard to guess (like youtube does with the links)

Comment: I'd say 2 is security by obscurity , as 'hard' to guess, is not really that 'hard' to guess from the attackers point of view.

Comment: I have generated a random type 4 UUID which I am holding in my hand. Now try guessing this 128 bits of entropy.

Comment: When you think about it, then a UUID has more entropy than a password used for authentication and authorization.

Comment: if you send those 128 bits of entropy , then i can access the data. It easily sharable... and once known, it cannot be invalidated unless you recalculate all the objects references.... not a trivial task if you have billions of objects. Where as authentication and authorisation can be revoked easily without recalculating object references. You can certainly use 1 and 2 together, in a solution, but 2 is not a standalone solution.

Comment: Well, this is what you use the indirect references for - for sharing things. And yes, you should not do this without thinking about it for a minute or two.